# When verifying whether a vector space is closed under addition, can we add the same vector to itself?

Tags: linear-algebra

This may seem like a silly question, but when verifying whether a vector space is closed under addition, can we add the same vector to itself?

For example, in the case of the question: '$W$ is the set of all vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ whose second component is the cube of the first' when the question is asking us to verify that the set is not a subspace of the vector space; could I use vector addition of $v = [3,27]^\top$ and $u = [3,27]^\top$ and then add $v + u$ to get $w = [6,54]^\top$ which is not an element of $W$ thus verifying that the set is not closed under addition?

Technically, I guess that it would be tantamount to scalar multiplication, but that could be used to verify that the set is not closed under scalar multiplication as well. I was wondering if this is an important distinction to be made, and how much difference it really makes.

Must I use a vector with a different value, implying that $v$ should not equal $u$? Sorry if this question sounds a little off, I was talking with someone about this topic and wasn't sure exactly what to think.

Comment: Yes, vector addition requires that you be able to add any two vectors, including two of the same vector. As you say this is also required by scalar multiplication by $2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  To be closed under addition, a vector space needs that the sum of _any_ pair of vectors in the vector space also be in the vector space. Here, you found an example that does not satisfy the condition, and hence the defined vector space is _not_ closed under addition. What you have done here is commonly known as a counterexample, perfect for disproving universal claims (e.g. "every pair of vectors...").

Comment: what you have done is you have shown that the "vector space" you defined is not actually a vector space... because if it were a vector space, then it would be closed under addition

Comment: Thanks everybody, thanks for your answers. All makes sense to me, seems legit.